# Add legend using geom_point and geom_smooth from different dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I really struggle to set the correct legend for a `geom_point` plot with loess regression, while there is 2 data set used

I got a data set, who is summarizing activity over a day, and then I plot on the same graph, all the activity per hours and per days recorded, plus a regression curve smoothed with a loess function, plus the mean of each hours for all the days.

To be more precise, here is an example of the first code, and the graph returned, without legend, which is exactly what I expected:

```
# first graph, which is given what I expected but with no legend
p <- ggplot(dat1, aes(x = Hour, y = value)) +
  geom_point(color = "darkgray", size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = dat2, mapping = aes(x = Hour, y = mean), 
             color = 20, size = 3) + 
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.2, color = "red", fill = "blue")
```

and the graph (in grey there is all the data, per hours, per days. the red curve is the loess regression. The blue dots are the means for each hours):

[image: in grey there is all the data, per hours, per days. the red curve is the loess regression. The blue dots are the means for each hours]

When I tried to set the legend I failed to plot one with the explanation for both kind of dots (data in grey, mean in blue), and the loess curve (in red). See below some example of what I tried.

```
# second graph, which is given what I expected + the legend for the loess that 
# I wanted but with not the dot legend

p <- ggplot(dat1, aes(x = Hour, y = value)) +
  geom_point(color = "darkgray", size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = dat2, mapping = aes(x = Hour, y = mean), 
             color = "blue", size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.2, aes(color = "red"), fill = "blue") +  
  scale_color_identity(name = "legend model", guide = "legend", 
                       labels = "loess regression \n with confidence interval")
```

I obtained the good legend for the curve only
[image]

and another trial :

```
# I tried to combine both date set into a single one as following but it did not 
# work at all and I really do not understand how the legends works in ggplot2 
# compared to the normal plots

A <- rbind(dat1, dat2)
p <- ggplot(A, aes(x = Heure, y = value, color = variable)) +
  geom_point(data = subset(A, variable == "data"), size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = subset(A, variable == "Moy"), size = 3) +
  geom_smooth(method = "loess", span = 0.2, aes(color = "red"), fill = "blue") +
  scale_color_manual(name = "légende", 
                     labels = c("Data", "Moy", "loess regression \n with confidence interval"), 
                     values = c("darkgray", "royalblue", "red"))
```

It appears that all the legend settings are mixed together in a "weird" way, the is a grey dot covering by a grey line, and then the same in blue and in red (for the 3 labels). all got a background filled in blue:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to label the mean, might need to be a bit creative, because it's not so easy to add legend manually in ggplot.

I simulate something that looks like your data below.

```
dat1 = data.frame(
       Hour = rep(1:24,each=10),
       value = c(rnorm(60,0,1),rnorm(60,2,1),rnorm(60,1,1),rnorm(60,-1,1))
)
# classify this as raw data
dat1$Data = "Raw"
# calculate mean like you did
dat2 <- dat1 %>% group_by(Hour) %>% summarise(value=mean(value))
# classify this as mean
dat2$Data = "Mean"

# combine the data frames
plotdat <- rbind(dat1,dat2)
# add a dummy variable, we'll use it later
plotdat$line = "Loess-Smooth"
```

We make the basic dot plot first:

```
ggplot(plotdat, aes(x = Hour, y = value,col=Data,size=Data)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","darkgray"))+
  scale_size_manual(values=c(3,1),guide=FALSE)
```

[image]

Note with the size, we set guide to FALSE so it will not appear. Now we add the loess smooth, one way to introduce the legend is to introduce a linetype, and since there's only one group, you will have just one variable:

```
ggplot(plotdat, aes(x = Hour, y = value,col=Data,size=Data)) +
  geom_point() + 
  scale_color_manual(values=c("blue","darkgray"))+
  scale_size_manual(values=c(3,1),guide=FALSE)+
  geom_smooth(data=subset(plotdat,Data="Raw"),
  aes(linetype=line),size=1,alpha=0.3,
         method = "loess", span = 0.2, color = "red", fill = "blue")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is exactly the perfect answer that I needed !